# How to provide login credentials with hg pull?

Tags: java, authentication, mercurial, dvcs

Is there any way of providing login credentials (Mercurial username and its password) with `hg pull` command? Or there is anyway of starting a session with particular user by providing username and password? I want to automate the mercurial pulling process using Java code and command line API.

I know there is a way of constructing the repository URL accordingly, e.g., `http://user:password@host/MercurialRepo` but this is not suitable to my case.

Comment: Which protocol to you pull over? HTTP, SSH, ...?

Comment: using ssh (and keys) should solve that

Answer (score 3):

Please see my [guide about remote repositories](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/remote/#caching-of-http-s-credentials). Your options depend on the protocol you use — it looks like you use HTTP from the example URL you give. In that case you can use

- [use the `auth` section](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#auth): this is secure as long as you protect your Mercurial config file. Native Mercurial solution so it works on all platforms.
- [keyring extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/KeyringExtension): this can be even more secure that the `auth` section since your OS can store the password in *encrypted* form on disk. The extension works on all platforms, but you need to install and configure it yourself — it's part of TortoiseHg, but not Mercurial itself.
- embed passwords in the URL: this is very easy but quite insecure and you've already rejected this.

Finally, since you mention Java, let me point you to [JavaHg](http://javahg.org/). This is a Java library for interacting with Mercurial. It doesn't have any special support for usernames and passwors in pull and clone (yet), so I suggest using the `auth` section with it for now.

Comment: Thank you Martin. It was really helpful to me. But what if the repository is hosted on SSH and I want to access it through a Java code. Of course I would have to run the HG commands from command-line utility in Java, but as you might be aware of, it will prompt me for password of the SSH user. Now how to handle this as there is no way of providing password along with the Repository URL?

Comment: @sra: I'm not sure. Perhaps you can set the `ui.ssh` setting in Mercurial to your own program. That program will then have to make a SSH connection to the remote host. I suggest looking at how MercurialEclipse does this. We'll eventually have to do the same for JavaHg, but we haven't gotten this far yet.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Martin. Actually I am developing an application in Java which will read all the Mercurial Commits or History to be precise. Now for this, I am left with only one choice to be used and that is Command-line API HG. I cannot use JavaHg due to some legality issues. So, from command-line options, I am stuck at this point. With HTTP there is an option of creating the Repository URL to accommodate username and password both, it has been working flawlessly.

Comment: And for a quick solution, is there any way of setting the ssh password in Mercurial.ini. If there is any, can you guide me to this point?

Comment: @sra: Can you comment on why you cannot use JavaHg — you're welcome to write me at martin@geisler.net if you like. We MIT licensed JavaHg so that there should be no concerns with using it in other projects. As for setting the SSH password in `Mercurial.ini`, then I'm afraid that's not possible: it is not Mercurial that prompts you for the password, it's your `ssh`.